# How to solve this compilation error?

Tags: compiler-errors

Unhandled Exception:
System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path "/home/sonic/Documents/gnututor_0.1/GnuTutor/GnuTutor/bin/Debug/~/Documents/gnututor_0.1/Databases\gnututor.pl".
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001cf] in :0 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.IO.FileOptions options, System.String msgPath, System.Boolean bFromProxy, System.Boolean useLongPath, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00000] in :0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream:.ctor (string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess,System.IO.FileShare,int,System.IO.FileOptions,string,bool,bool,bool)
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean checkHost) [0x00079] in :0 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Text.Encoding encoding, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks, System.Int32 bufferSize) [0x00000] in :0 
  at System.IO.StreamReader..ctor (System.String path, System.Boolean detectEncodingFromByteOrderMarks) [0x0000d] in :0

Comment: Please provide the code you tried to compile as well.

Comment: its an exe file while iam using mono to run
but the app.config file include the path and here is the source code of that app.config
  <appSettings>
    <add key="DatabasePath" value="~/Documents/Databases\" />
    <add key="LogPath" value="~/Documents/LogFiles\" />
    <add key="DialogueFile" value="gnututor.pl" />

Comment: Please put this in your original post with the code formatting ;-)

Comment: it is already a compiled code but when i run the .exe file using mono the above compilation is shown i think its the path which is creating the problem iam typing in the path correctly ! for Databases and logfiles. and by the way iam using linux operating system